# Golang-like defer in Rust

Tags: go, rust

In Go, you can use the `defer` keyword to execute a function when the current function returns, similar to the traditional `finally` keyword in other languages. This is useful for cleaning up state regardless of what happens throughout the function body. Here's an example from the Go blog:

```
func CopyFile(dstName, srcName string) (written int64, err error) {
    src, err := os.Open(srcName)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer src.Close()

    dst, err := os.Create(dstName)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer dst.Close()

    return io.Copy(dst, src)
}
```

How can this functionality be achieved in Rust? I know about RAII, but in my specific case the state is in an external system. I'm writing a test that writes a key to a key-value store, and I need to make sure it's deleted at the end of the test regardless of whether or not the assertions in the test cause a panic.

I found [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/karablin/8568808) but I don't know if this is a recommended approach. The unsafe destructor is worrisome.

There is also [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/1523) on the Rust GitHub repository, but it's three years old and clearly not very relevant anymore.

Comment: I don't know a lot of Rust, but wouldn't a function that takes a closure suffice?

Comment: Of course, regular files opened using Rust's libstd will close in their drop glue by themselves.

Comment: @Ainar-G, sorry for the late answer and the jargon. Defer could be achieved with a Newtype implementing `Drop` and executing a closure you passed when creating the Newtype. However closures close over variables and then lifetimes are problematic. Let's say you close over a variable you already moved when the Newtype is going out of scope. This won't compile. I think you'll need a closure where the variables you close over move into the closure and will not be available anymore. I am not sure, but using huon's `defer!` macro seems to solve this problem because it doesn't close over anything.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

(*e:* don't miss bluss's answer and their [scopedguard](https://crates.io/crates/scopeguard) crate, below.)

The correct way to achieve this by having code that runs in a destructor, like the `defer!` macro you link to does. For anything more than ad-hoc testing I would recommend writing a handle type with a proper destructor, e.g. one interacts with `std::sync::Mutex` via its [`MutexGuard`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html) type (returned by `lock`): there's no need to call `unlock` on the mutex itself. (The explicit handle-with-destructor approach is more flexible too: it has mutable access to the data, whereas the deferred approach may not be able to, due to Rust's strong aliasing controls.)

In any case, that macro is now (much!) improved due to recent changes, in particular, pnkfelix's [sound generic drop work](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0769-sound-generic-drop.md), which removes the necessity for `#[unsafe_destructor]`. The direct update would be:

```
struct ScopeCall<F: FnMut()> {
    c: F
}
impl<F: FnMut()> Drop for ScopeCall<F> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        (self.c)();
    }
}

macro_rules! defer {
    ($e:expr) => (
        let _scope_call = ScopeCall { c: || -> () { $e; } };
    )
}

fn main() {
    let x = 42u8;
    defer!(println!("defer 1"));
    defer!({
        println!("defer 2");
        println!("inside defer {}", x)
    });
    println!("normal execution {}", x);
}
```

Output:

```
normal execution 42
defer 2
inside defer 42
defer 1
```

---

Although, it would be syntactically nicer as:

```
macro_rules! expr { ($e: expr) => { $e } } // tt hack
macro_rules! defer {
    ($($data: tt)*) => (
        let _scope_call = ScopeCall { 
            c: || -> () { expr!({ $($data)* }) }
        };
    )
}
```

(The `tt hack` is necessary due to [#5846](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/5846).)

The use of the generic `tt` ("token tree") allows one to invoke it without the inner `{ ... }` when there are multiple statements (i.e. it behaves more like a "normal" control flow structure):

```
defer! {
    println!("defer 2");
    println!("inside defer {}", x)
}
```

Also, for maximum flexibility about what the deferred code can do with captured variables, one could use `FnOnce` instead of `FnMut`:

```
struct ScopeCall<F: FnOnce()> {
    c: Option<F>
}
impl<F: FnOnce()> Drop for ScopeCall<F> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.c.take().unwrap()()
    }
}
```

That will also require constructing the `ScopeCall` with a `Some` around the value for `c`. The `Option` dance is required because calling a `FnOnce` moves ownership, which isn't possible from behind `self: &mut ScopeCall<F>` without it. (Doing this is OK, since the destructor only executes once.)

All in all:

```
struct ScopeCall<F: FnOnce()> {
    c: Option<F>
}
impl<F: FnOnce()> Drop for ScopeCall<F> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        self.c.take().unwrap()()
    }
}

macro_rules! expr { ($e: expr) => { $e } } // tt hack
macro_rules! defer {
    ($($data: tt)*) => (
        let _scope_call = ScopeCall {
            c: Some(|| -> () { expr!({ $($data)* }) })
        };
    )
}

fn main() {
    let x = 42u8;
    defer!(println!("defer 1"));
    defer! {
        println!("defer 2");
        println!("inside defer {}", x)
    }
    println!("normal execution {}", x);
}
```

(Same output as the original.)

Comment: How do we use this with `async` calls?

Answer (score 28):

I use the following for a scope guard. It uses the `Deref` traits to provide shared & mutable access to the guarded value, without moving it out (that would invalidate the guard!)

My use case is correctly resetting the terminal when the program exits, even if panicking:

```rust
extern crate scopeguard;
use scopeguard::guard;

// ... terminal setup omitted ...

// Use a scope guard to restore terminal settings on quit/panic
let mut tty = guard(tty, |tty| {
    // ... I use tty.write() here too ...
    ts::tcsetattr(tty.as_raw_fd(), ts::TCSANOW, &old_attr).ok();
});
game_main(&mut tty).unwrap();   // Deref coercion magic hands off the inner &mut TTY pointer here.
```

Module scopeguard.rs:

```rust
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

pub struct Guard<T, F> where
    F: FnMut(&mut T)
{
    __dropfn: F,
    __value: T,
}

pub fn guard<T, F>(v: T, dropfn: F) -> Guard<T, F> where
    F: FnMut(&mut T)
{
    Guard{__value: v, __dropfn: dropfn}
}

impl<T, F> Deref for Guard<T, F> where
    F: FnMut(&mut T)
{
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &T
    {
        &self.__value
    }

}

impl<T, F> DerefMut for Guard<T, F> where
    F: FnMut(&mut T)
{
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T
    {
        &mut self.__value
    }
}

impl<T, F> Drop for Guard<T, F> where
    F: FnMut(&mut T)
{
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        (self.__dropfn)(&mut self.__value)
    }
}
```

This is now the crate [scopeguard  on crates.io.](https://crates.io/crates/scopeguard)

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers, cause this is really awesome, and likely what I will actually use. Thank you!